# MySQL - Sort by multiple keywords

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce

Writing an eCommerce for a local business. Got it all sorted and such, just working out the kinks.

Now they have a lot of products that are the same, but just differ by colour. So i need some help on sorting by said colour. They are named by the following.

[Manufacturer] - [Colour] - [Series]

Example: Art Spectrum - **Primrose Yellow** - Series 1

I'd need them to be sorted by **Yellow** but sometimes they don't have a certain type of colour. Like just Yellow, instead of Primrose Yellow. Also, there are multiple colours in the database - red, green, blue etc and all have variants.

Anyway, how would i sort by this?

Thanks

Comment: You need to sort or to filter (select) based on color?

Comment: Sort, sorry i changed my post to be more clear.

Comment: You should start by normalising your database. Split "[Manufacturer] - [Colour] - [Series]" out into three separate tables. Then you can try sorting.

Comment: That wouldn't really work, since it's a general site, only paints are formatted like that and they have a ton of other products that don't sit with that format.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you can try

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM products
 ORDER BY TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(prod_name, '-', 2),'-', -1)
```

*That will obviously let you sort only by exact match of color names*

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95a4a/10)**

**UPDATE** Now, you can easily create a color matching table like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE colors
    (`color` varchar(64), `color2` varchar(64))
;
```

Fill it with matching colors

```
|           COLOR | COLOR2 |
----------------------------
| Primrose Yellow | Yellow |
```

You can initially fill the `color` field in this table with a query like this

```sql
INSERT INTO colors (color)
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(prod_name, '-', 2),'-', -1))
  FROM products
```

Then you can use this query to do what you want

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     colors c ON TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.prod_name, '-', 2),'-', -1)) = c.color
ORDER BY COALESCE(c.color2, TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.prod_name, '-', 2),'-', -1)))
```

*If there are no entries for particular color in a color matching table result set will be sorted anyway based on an actual color value found in a product name* That means that you can fill it gradually.

Output

```
| ID |                                 PROD_NAME |
--------------------------------------------------
|  2 |                    Art 2 - Red - Series 1 |
|  1 | Art Spectrum - Primrose Yellow - Series 1 |
|  3 |         Art Spectrum2 - Yellow - Series 2 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9a30/1)** for that

Comment: I just gave that a shot, it's kind of what i want. http://i.imgur.com/OxwN9Kc.png

Comment: I like that idea. Instead of doing the substring, because some items don't use that exact format, is there a way to do a fulltext match. like ORDER BY (SELECT color12 FROM colors WHERE color1 LIKE product.name)

Comment: @Aaron FTS is only available in MyISAM and I'm not sure how apply it to sorting in your case. I think a matching color table approach can give you pretty decent results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `Full TEXT` index search here.

But Full-text searches are supported for `MyISAM` tables only.

Add `FULLTEXT` index to your column, then use the following query:

**Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE MATCH (column_name)
AGAINST ('Yellow' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: That could work. But how would i do that with all major colours?